# XUBUNTU 18.10- Blank screen after waking from suspend

Tags: xubuntu, suspend, login-screen, 18.10

Whenever i press any button to wake my system from suspend it screen get on with grey background and mouse poniter then w/o showing the login screen goes blank..

After that no matter what i do the screen doesn't show..

If i enter the password then everything goes back to normal..

This does't happen when i lock the screen.. In lock screen when i press the button i get the login screen but in suspend it gets blank..

This didn't happen in any other linux distro.. Please help..

Answer (score 1):

I found a discussion of this issue in the Xubuntu support email list, archived [here](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/xubuntu-users/2018-November/010862.html). Unfortunately the suggestion is a rather wonky workaround that requires a GNOME reversion:

> Installing gnome-screensaver (which required no dependencies) and
>   unchecking light locker from startup applications.